# Is there a mistake in my custom percentile function? Or am I misusing numpy's percentile function?

Tags: numpy, statistics, data-analysis, percentile

According to the definition of the (100p)th percentile in Ross's Introductory Statistics (3ed):

"Suppose the data from a sample of size n are arranged in increasing order from smallest to largest. To determine the sample 100p percentile, we must determine the data value such that

1. At least np of the data values are less than or equal to it.
2. At least n(1−p) of the data values are greater than or equal to it." (page 90)

I have made my own percentile function, which is:

```
def calculate_percentile(data, p):

    sorted_data = np.sort(data)
    n = len(data)

    if (n * p).is_integer() == True:
       percentile = (data[(n * p) - 1] + data[(n*p)])/2  
                                                          
    else:
       percentile = data[math.ceil((n * p) - 1)]
    
    return percentile
```

The idea is this. First we sort the data into ascending order. Then we calculate the (100p)th percentile in the following way. If n * p is an integer, then we get the average of the values in positions np and np + 1. Since python indexing starts at 0, the index np becomes np - 1 and np + 1 becomes just np. Finally, if n * p is not an integer, then we want the data value whose position is the smallest integer greater than n * p. To achieve this, I used the ceil() function to get the next value along.

So, this should work, as far as I can tell: i've implemented Ross's instructions in python. Except, when I've tested my function on a data set I get a different result to the standard numpy.percentile() function. In particular, given the following data set:

```
data1 = np.array([
    19, 34, 25, 34, 23, 20, 24, 31, 34, 34, 28, 27,     32, 39, 31, 19, 24, 21, 19,
    30, 37, 32, 20, 20, 35, 28, 28, 40, 20, 21, 18, 33, 35, 30, 40, 29, 31, 36,
    27, 21, 34, 38, 21, 29, 37, 27, 18, 35, 36, 40, 23, 25, 35, 19, 29, 20, 28,
    26, 30, 28, 19, 37, 37, 36, 40, 37, 19, 19, 40, 36, 22, 24, 38, 21, 40, 19,
    35, 18, 19, 22, 29, 25, 22, 18, 34, 20, 35, 34, 24, 22, 20, 30, 40, 32, 38,
    33, 26, 35, 22, 21, 26, 33, 25, 19, 39, 18, 18, 22, 24, 39, 38, 24, 30, 20,
    21, 23, 19, 23, 28, 20, 35, 25, 30, 22, 22, 27, 19, 26, 39, 18, 20, 19, 27,
    18, 30, 31, 28, 26, 27, 18, 22, 21, 34, 30, 20, 19, 38, 35, 24, 26, 21, 19,
    18, 35, 39, 35, 18, 37, 22, 19, 25, 33, 29, 40, 27, 38, 20, 25, 26, 27, 29,
    18, 37, 25, 19, 34, 39, 21, 32, 29, 23, 31, 36, 27, 32, 25, 29, 40, 28, 31,
    28, 31, 39, 39, 28, 21, 35, 29, 35, 37, 37, 21, 21, 37, 32, 25, 32, 36, 20,
    28, 32, 40, 24, 36, 28, 28, 29, 28, 39, 38, 28, 25, 39, 22, 33, 18, 32, 24,
    28, 27, 34, 22, 32, 29, 36, 23, 38, 34, 39, 19, 20, 18, 21, 36, 29, 40, 26,
    28, 24, 40, 25, 26, 35, 24, 20, 23, 25, 18, 19, 28, 30, 28, 37, 31, 26, 30,
    34, 29, 31, 40, 37, 24, 21, 27, 40, 23, 20, 19,   23, 37, 36, 31, 33, 29, 40
    ])
```

my function gets me:

```
34
```

whereas

```
np.percentile(data1,0.03)
```

gets me

```
18.0
```

So, is there a mistake in my percentile function, or am I calling the np.percentile function with incorrect arguments (i've read something about an interpolation parameter)? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple mistake: `sorted_data` is unused in the function. You should use `sorted_data` instead of `data`. This then gives the same result for p=0.03.

Note that the formula `(data[(n * p) - 1] + data[(n*p)])/2` is certainly not correct. Generally, a *linear interpolation* is performed between the two value regarding the percentage, not just a mean of the two values.

Comment: Thank you! Regarding your second point: are you saying that both my function and the percentile function without interpolation parameter specified  are getting it wrong? How ought I to correct this? I thought I was just implementing Ross's definition: "The sample 100p percentile is that data value having the property that at least 100p percent of the data are less than or equal to it and at least 100(1 − p) percent of the data values are greater than or equal to it. If two data values satisfy this condition, then the sample 100p percentile is the arithmetic average of these values."

Comment: Try with `np.percentile(np.array([0.0, 1.0]), 3)`: the result is 0.03. Your function gives 0.0 even when the sort is fixed. You need to compute the remainder between the two values with `np.fmod` and the do a linear interpolation (either manually or possibly with Scipy as it should be able to do that). Manually it should be something like `rem * val1 + (1-rem) * val2` where `val1` and `val2` are the value to be interpolated and `rem` is the remainder (coef of the linear interpolation).

Comment: `np.percentile` has actually a `method` parameter for that and it is set to `'linear'` by default. If you want to use another method for your implementation, it is fine, but you need to specify this to `np.percentile` too so to compare equivalent things.